# How to Test Sampling Methods

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, fishers-exact-test, mcnemar-test

Suppose I have a population, $P$, of 100 individuals and I am devising 3 algorithmic methods to sample 20 people from said population: $A$, $B$, and $C$. We know that $C$ is a random, unbiased algorithm.

Suppose the outputs for each algorithm are 100-length lists of 0's and 1's. Binary data where a 1 indicated that an individual is selected for a sample. There are 20 1's in each list:

$A(P)$ = $[0, 1, 0, 1, ... , 1]$

$B(P)$ = $[1, 0, 1, 1, ... , 0]$

$C(P)$ = $[1, 0, 0, 1, ... , 1]$

If I *know* that C is random, but I suspect that $A$ is *not* random and that $B$ *is* random, how can I go about testing this? I initially tried McNemar's test due to having paired nominal data. But then realized the statistic would always be 0 since my each list contains exactly 20 1's.
Is Fisher's Exact test the best test for this type of experiment? How can I test a suspicion that $B$ is likely random (or similar to $C$) and show that the opposite is true for $A$?

Comment: It's impossible to discern whether any sample is random based on this information.  For instance, after obtaining sample $C,$ the experimenter might have numbered the population members so that the first 20 are in $C,$ whence $C(P) = (1,1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0).$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that the sequence of items is not important and has not been rearranged after one of the selection processes (see the comment of whuber), this sounds like a classical application of the Wald-Wolfowitz runs test, see [Runs Test for Detecting Nonrandomness](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35d.htm) or [Wald-Wolfowitz runs test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test). For example, in your case with $N_+=20$ and $N_-=80$ one gets a mean number of runs $\mu = 33$ with a standard deviation $\sigma =  3.17$, which can be used as basis for the hypothesis test. But please check, that this is based on the randomness / unbiasedness you are assuming.